# Payara Consume/Produce messages from/to ActiveMQ Artemis

Tags: jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-artemis, payara

I have an application that runs on a Payara 4.1.2.173. The application should be sending and receiving JMS messages, so to do so, I use Apache ActiveMQ Artemis. I chose ActiveMQ Artemis because ActiveMQ only supports JMS 1.1, while ActiveMQ Artemis supports JMS 2.0.

But I find it odd that ActiveMQ Artemis does not provide a resource adapter (.rar file), while ActiveMQ does provide one. The good part is, the resource adapter for ActiveMQ is able to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis. The sad part is, it only supports JMS 1.1, so the benefits of Artemis (for me) are not available.

While using JMS 1.1, it's easy to create a Consumer (MDB style), but when I want to Produce messages, I would need to handle the setup of the connection by myself. I read the documentation, and it seems like JMS 2.0 should support injecting a JMSContext, which can be used to create a producer without the need of setting up the connection itself.

But the ActiveMQ RA does not support injecting a JMSContext, it only allows to inject JMSConnectionFactory.

Is there a way so I can inject a JMSContext, which is configured to connect to ActiveMQ Artemis?

I was already thinking of using the included `jmsra` RA straight from Payara, but I can't figure out how to configure it.

Answer (score 2):

ActiveMQ Artemis provides a RAR file, but it's no easy to find it and it's probably not documented anywhere: https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/artemis-ra

Maven dependency: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.apache.activemq%22%20AND%20a%3A%22artemis-ra%22
Example: https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/sub-modules/artemis-ra-rar

I would be interested if it works. I want to try it myself but don't have much time to do it.

Comment: Thanks! The rar works for creating a connectionfactory to get it injected, and configure an MDB. But I can not define any queues as admin objects, to have them injected. I just need to inject the JMSContext, and create the queue by myself.

Comment: @Erates artemis-ra seems to be a .jar file. how did you managed to add it to Payara ?

Comment: The RAR project is surprisingly in examples: https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/tree/master/examples/features/sub-modules/artemis-ra-rar